# Is there a way to get a current option value from within the monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

After launching the CLI and loading a wallet, you can issue commands; a list of which is available from `help` and `help all`.

The `help set` command shows a listing of options which can be set with `set <option-name> <option-value>`, however, I can't figure out a way to *get* the current value of an option. A common pattern of just not specifying `<option-value>` does not work.

If these runtime values cannot be retrieved from within the CLI, where are they persisted on disk when they deviate from the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type `set` and hit return. That lists all the currently set values.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that. Now to figure out how to submit a PR for the CLI help...

Comment: works in DOS, Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, and MacOS too. :)

Comment: @Dave Sure, but on *nix, at least I could grep the output to find the option I care about. No grep inside of the interactive wallet cli!

Comment: @NReilingh `monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file MyWallet --password 'X' set | grep auto-refresh`